# how do i change the ContentPlaceholder id of an asp content tag dynamically

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an asp content tag with ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" I want to change the contentplaceholder id to  "ContentPlaceHolder2" but I get the error object reference not set to an instance of an object. note// I have both content placeholders present on my master page.
below is my code

```
 //html code of my content page
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server" ID="plsid">

</asp:Content>

 //code behind of my content page
 Protected Sub Btndetails_Command(sender As Object, e As CommandEventArgs)
    
    
    Dim u As String = "ContentPlaceHolder2"
    CType(Page.FindControl("plsid"), Content).ContentPlaceHolderID = u


    
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you set `ClientIDMode="static"`? Also, [Is there any drawback to set ClientIDMode = Static on every object ( set on maincontent of master page)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.content.contentplaceholderid?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_UI_WebControls_Content_ContentPlaceHolderID).

Comment: Yes I have but still same problem

Comment: Which object is it referring to? Is it the result of `Page.FindControl("plsid")`? You could put it in a separate variable to make it easier to find out, like `Dim ctrl = Page.FindControl("plsid")` and then check if `ctrl Is Nothing`. That will narrow down where you need to investigate.

Comment: ok let me try that please

Comment: ' Yes I did this and it says ctt is nothing
        Dim u As String = "ContentPlaceHolder2"
        Dim ctt = CType(Page.FindControl("plsid"), Content)
        ctt.ContentPlaceHolderID = u

Comment: Normally you wouldn't have to find the control, you would just use `plsid.ContentPlaceHolderID = u`. What happens when you try that?

Comment: the asp:content control does not even register "plsid" as the ID of the control so codebehid does not recognise "plsid" as an ID meanwhile on the html, i have set the ID of the control to be = plsid

Comment: After a little bit more investigation, I think that what I think you might want to do is explained in [Multiple ContentPlaceHolders and Default Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/master-pages/multiple-contentplaceholders-and-default-content-cs).